# "socket closed" error when I try to send/receive a jxrpc over a socket stream

Tags: java, jackson

This is my code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false);//suggested by fge

Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",port);
mapper.writeValue(s.getOutputStream(),anObjectRequest);//this works
Aresponse res = mapper.readValue(s.getInputStream(),AresponseClass.class);
```

I get that the socket is closed.

But, if look into wireshark, I see the server correctly receives the request and correctly sends the answer too!
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()

> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket

What type is mapper?  Does this method:

```
mapper.writeValue(s.getOutputStream(),anObjectRequest);//this works
```

call close on the `OutputStream` object?

Assuming you are using an [`ObjectMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> Note: method does not close the underlying stream explicitly here; however, JsonFactory this mapper uses may choose to close the stream depending on its settings (by default, it will try to close it when JsonGenerator we construct is closed).

You'll have to pay attention to which `JsonFactory` you are using.

Comment: Can somebody who is better than me at formatting stackoverflow fix the 2nd link

Comment: yes it is an ObjectMapper (edited question) but I don't specify any json factory when I create it...so how to set this behaviour right?

Comment: And you're right, it closes by default; the OP should `mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, false)`

Comment: Ok it works! The correct option to set, in my case, was: mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET,false); as it was the generator to close the socket (but I will do the same with the parser ;) )